# np.random.norm function to take the mean/standard deviation

Tags: python

I would like the np.random.normal function to output an array the shape of (6,12,25) using each mean and standard deviation corresponding to each other (like mean[0],stdev[0] then mean[1],stdev[1], etc.). I tried this:

```
rand_vars = []

for basin in range(6):
    for month in range(12):
        rand_vars.append(np.random.normal(mean_monthly_ts[basin,month],stdev_monthly_ts[basin,month],time_years[-25:].size))
rand_vars=np.array(rand_vars)

print(rand_vars.shape)
(72, 25)
```

but the shape of rand_var is off, giving 72,25 instead of 6,12,25. I think I am overriding something in my for loop with or my mean and standard deviations are not aligning with the correct indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add to the end of your code:

```
rand_vars=np.reshape(rand_vars,[6,12,25])
```

If you want to verify reshaping, let us consider the following modifications (for verifications only):

```
import numpy as np
rand_vars = []
for basin in range(6):
    for month in range(12):
        a=[ basin*100+month for i in range(25)] # just for verification purboses
        rand_vars.append(a)
rand_vars=np.array(rand_vars)
rand_vars=np.reshape(rand_vars,[6,12,25])
```

```
rand_vars[0][0]
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0])
```

```
rand_vars[2][1]
array([201, 201, 201, 201, 201, 201, 201, 201, 201, 201, 201, 201, 201,
```

and so on